# I seem to be getting a HTTP403 error here. Here's the code I wrote to access location on my Google Maps. I input the proper Google Maps Api key

Tags: flutter, google-maps, dart

I generated the Google maps API key in the Google console by activating the Maps and Places APIs and generating a singular API key .Here's the code where I input the Google Maps API key and generate the latitude and longitude

```
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = "I entered my API KEY here";



class LocationHelper {
  static String generateLocationPreviewImage({double latitude, double longitude}) {
    return "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=&$latitude,$longitude&zoom=13&size=600x300&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:red%7Clabel:C%7C$latitude,$longitude&key=$GOOGLE_API_KEY";
  }
}
```

I used the code in this widget snippet so as to gain access to the API key and update the image holding container upon pressing current location to show location

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';

import '../helpers/location_helper.dart';

class LocationInput extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LocationInputState createState() => _LocationInputState();
}

class _LocationInputState extends State<LocationInput> {
  String _previewImageUrl;

  Future<void> _getCurrentUserLocation () async {
    final locData = await Location().getLocation();
   final staticMapImageUrl = LocationHelper.generateLocationPreviewImage(
     latitude: locData.latitude,
     longitude: locData.longitude,
   );
   setState(() {
     _previewImageUrl = staticMapImageUrl;
   });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: 200,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
            border: Border.all(
              width: 1,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
          child: _previewImageUrl == null
              ? Text(
                  "No location found",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                )
              : Image.network(_previewImageUrl,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover, width: double.infinity),
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton.icon(
              label: Text(
                "Current Location",
              ),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              icon: Icon(Icons.location_on),
              onPressed: _getCurrentUserLocation ,
            ),
            FlatButton.icon(
              label: Text(
                "Select on Map",
              ),
              textColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              icon: Icon(Icons.map),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Upon pressing the Current Location button ,I seem to keep getting a HTTP 403 error message despite inputting the right API key. May anyone know the reason why?

Comment: I see that you're calling [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview) but you mentioned that you just activated "Maps and Places APIs". To use the Maps Static API, make sure that the API is enabled in your project and the project is linked to an open billing account.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that my comment above worked, I'm putting it here as the answer: I see that you're calling [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview) but you mentioned that you just activated "Maps and Places APIs". To use the Maps Static API, make sure that the API is enabled in your project and the project is linked to an open billing account as stated in the [doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/overview):

> Before you start using the Maps Static API, you need a project with a
> billing account and the Maps Static API enabled. We recommend creating
> multiple Project Owners and Billing Administrators, so that you'll
> always have someone with these roles available to your team.